# Ignore history when using zsh

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I set the `HISTORY_IGNORE` variable in `~/.zshrc` and it correctly prevents those commands from being written to `~/.zsh_history`.

But what I really want is for those entries not to show when pressing <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd>. (Same as `HISTIGNORE` when using bash).

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a hook for that. As it says [in the `HISTORY_IGNORE` documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Used-By-The-Shell):

> Compare the `HIST_NO_STORE` option or the `zshaddhistory` hook, either of
> which would prevent such commands from being added to the interactive
> history at all. If you wish to use `HISTORY_IGNORE` to stop history
> being added in the first place, you can define the following hook:
>
> ```bsh
> zshaddhistory() {
>   emulate -L zsh
>   ## uncomment if HISTORY_IGNORE
>   ## should use EXTENDED_GLOB syntax
>   # setopt extendedglob
>   [[ $1 != ${~HISTORY_IGNORE} ]]
> }
> ```

Important findings from my own testing:

- `$1` includes a *line break* at the end. Be aware of this when writing your pattern for `HISTORY_IGNORE`. If it doesn't account for it, it won't match.
- This function is applied whenever Zsh writes your history from its memory to your history file. Thus, it will *retroactively* remove lines from your history. Be careful with this!

Comment: I added that to `/.zshrc` but the commands I excluded in `HISTORY_IGNORE` still show up in <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd>.

Comment: As it says in the [documentation for `zshaddhistory`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions): "If any of the hook functions returns status 1 (or any non-zero value other than 2, though this is not guaranteed for future versions of the shell) the history line will not be saved, although it lingers in the history until the next line is executed, allowing you to reuse or edit it immediately." Thus, after executing the command that you want history to ignore, first execute a new command and _then_ try to see if the command you wanted to ignore is gone.

Comment: Thanks, though that  doesn't work for me either. Maybe a version or dependency problem. Does this actually work for you?

Comment: Yes, it does. If use that function and set `HISTORY_IGNORE='*'`, then nothing gets added to my history. I'm using Zsh 5.8.

Comment: I just tested it and `$1` includes a _line break_ at the end for me. It might be that's why your pattern doesn't match.

Comment: Mind you, something else I discovered: This is applied _retroactively._ So, I just managed to wipe my entire history with `HISTORY_IGNORE='*'`. Good thing I have backups!